# In mongodb how do I replace array field with null value to an empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to replace an array field in document that has value of null to an empty array [].  I tried this query but it's not working.  Please help.

Basically I want **testArray: null** to be **testArray: []**

```
db.myTestCollection.aggregate( { "_id": ObjectId('1120191011212112') },
   [ { $set: { testArray: { $ifNull: [ { $concatArrays: [ "$testArray", [] ] } ] } } }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you mostly have a syntax error. But you can also move the `$ifNull` logic into the filter predicate as well so that no update is considered/applied if the existing `testArray` field isn't already `null`. So:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1,
  "testArray": null
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      testArray: []
    }
  }
])
```

Working [playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Quv3_MdCl-X).